# Ways to Create Tables and Presentable Objects Other than Plots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, graphic

I have the following code that runs through the following:

Draw a number of points from a true distribution.
Use those points with curve_fit to extract the parameters.
Check if those parameters are, on average, close to the true values.
(You can do this by creating the "Pull distribution" and see if it returns
a standard normal variable.

```
# This script calculates the mean and standard deviation for
# the pull distributions on the estimators that curve_fit returns

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gauss
import format

numTrials = 10000
# Pull given by (a_j - a_true)/a_error)
error_vec_A = [] 
error_vec_mean = []
error_vec_sigma = []

# Loop to determine pull distribution
for i in xrange(0,numTrials):

    # Draw from primary distribution
    mean = 0; var = 1; sigma = np.sqrt(var); 
    N = 20000
    A = 1/np.sqrt((2*np.pi*var))
    points = gauss.draw_1dGauss(mean,var,N)

    # Histogram parameters
    bin_size = 0.1; min_edge = mean-6*sigma; max_edge = mean+9*sigma
    Nn = (max_edge-min_edge)/bin_size; Nplus1 = Nn + 1
    bins = np.linspace(min_edge, max_edge, Nplus1)

    # Obtain histogram from primary distributions    
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(points,bins,density=True)
    bin_centres = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:])/2

    # Initial guess
    p0 = [5, 2, 4]

    coeff, var_matrix = curve_fit(gauss.gaussFun, bin_centres, hist, p0=p0)

    # Get the fitted curve
    hist_fit = gauss.gaussFun(bin_centres, *coeff)

    # Error on the estimates
    error_parameters = np.sqrt(np.array([var_matrix[0][0],var_matrix[1][1],var_matrix[2][2]]))

    # Obtain the error for each value: A,mu,sigma 
    A_std = (coeff[0]-A)/error_parameters[0]
    mean_std = ((coeff[1]-mean)/error_parameters[1])
    sigma_std = (np.abs(coeff[2])-sigma)/error_parameters[2]

    # Store results in container
    error_vec_A.append(A_std)
    error_vec_mean.append(mean_std)
    error_vec_sigma.append(sigma_std)

# Plot the distribution of each estimator        
plt.figure(1); plt.hist(error_vec_A,bins,normed=True); plt.title('Pull of A')
plt.figure(2); plt.hist(error_vec_mean,bins,normed=True); plt.title('Pull of Mu')
plt.figure(3); plt.hist(error_vec_sigma,bins,normed=True); plt.title('Pull of Sigma')

# Store key information regarding distribution 
mean_A = np.mean(error_vec_A); sigma_A = np.std(error_vec_A)    
mean_mu = np.mean(error_vec_mean); sigma_mu = np.std(error_vec_mean)    
mean_sigma = np.mean(error_vec_sigma); sigma_sig = np.std(error_vec_sigma)    
info = np.array([[mean_A,sigma_A],[mean_mu,sigma_mu],[mean_sigma,sigma_sig]])
```

My problem is I don't know how to use python to format the data into a table. I have to manually go into the variables and go to google docs to present the information. I'm just wondering how I can do that using pandas or some other library.

Here's an example of the manual insertion:

```
                          Trial 1   Trial 2  Trial 3
Seed                     [0.2,0,1] [10,2,5]  [5,2,4]
Bins for individual runs    20        20        20
Points Thrown              1000      1000      1000
Number of Runs             5000      5000      5000
Bins for pull dist fit      20        20        20
Mean_A                   -0.11177  -0.12249  -0.10965
sigma_A                   1.17442   1.17517   1.17134
Mean_mu                   0.00933  -0.02773  -0.01153
sigma_mu                  1.38780   1.38203   1.38671
Mean_sig                  0.05292   0.06694   0.04670
sigma_sig                 1.19411   1.18438   1.19039
```

I would like to automate this table so If I change my parameters in my code, I get a new table with that new data.

Comment: I am curious as to why this question was voted down. Legitimate question, IMO.

Comment: On the other hand, you are on the right track thinking about pandas. Have you tried reading the API documentation? There are a few good examples on how you can: (1) convert lists of lists into DataFrames, and (2) save the DataFrames as CSV files.

Comment: @ericmjl 

Thanks!

I did a while ago but I haven't been able to output data tables as I've wanted. Those examples you're referring to should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to generate a presentable table.

Answer (score 1):

if you're not already using it, the [IPython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) is really good for rendering [rich display](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb) formats. It's really good in a lot of other ways, too.

It will render pandas dataframe objects as an html table when they're either the last, unreturned value in a cell or if you explicitly call `Ipython.core.display.display` function instead of print.

If you're not already using pandas, I highly recommend it. It's basically a wrapper around 2D & 3D numpy arrays; it's just as fast, but it has nice naming conventions, data grouping and filtering funcitons, and some other cool stuff.

At that point, it depends on how you want to present it. You can use [nbconvert](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.0.0/interactive/nbconvert.html) to render a whole notebook as static html or a pdf. You can copy-paste the html table into Excel or PowerPoint or an E-mail.